# why is there a syntax error at line 27/ pine_vwmean?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
strategy("HOSS Scalping", overlay=true)

// Custom OBV RSI Indicator
OBVIndicator() =>
    obvsrc = close
    change_1 = change(obvsrc)
    obv = cum(change(obvsrc) > 0 ? volume : change_1 < 0 ? -volume : 0 * volume)

    src = obv
    len = 5
    up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
    down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
    rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)
    rsi
// Custom VWAP Indicator
VWAPIndicator() => 
    ls = false
    type = 'Average Deviation'
    length = 60
    source = close
    _low = ls == true ? math.log(low) : low
    _high = ls == true ? math.log(high) : high
    src = ls == true ? math.log(source) : source

    //weighted mean
    pine_vwmean(x, y) =>
        cw = 0
        cd = 0.0
        w_sum = 0.0
        d_sum = 0.0
        for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
            cd = x[i]
            cw = volume[i]
            d_sum += cw * cd
            w_sum += cw
        d_sum / w_sum

    //weighted standard deviation
    pine_vwstdev(x, y, b) =>
        d_sum = 0.0
        w_sum = 0.0
        cd = 0.0
        for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
            cd = x[i]
            cw = volume[i]
            d_sum += cw * math.pow(cd - b, 2)
            w_sum += cw
        math.sqrt(d_sum / w_sum)

    //weighted average deviation
    pine_vwavdev(x, y, b) =>
        d_sum = 0.0
        w_sum = 0.0
        cd = 0.0
        for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
            cd = x[i]
            cw = volume[i]
            d_sum += cw * math.abs(cd - b)
            w_sum += cw
        d_sum / w_sum

    vwmean = pine_vwmean(src, length)

    dev = if type == 'Standard Deviation'
        dev = pine_vwstdev(src, length, vwmean)
        dev
    else if type == 'Average Deviation'
        dev = pine_vwavdev(src, length, vwmean)
        dev

// Long Entry Conditions



obvRsi = OBVIndicator()

[vwmean, dev] = VWAPIndicator()
lowerDev2 = vwmean - 2 * dev
lowerDev3 = vwmean - 3 * dev

longCondition = close[1] > lowerDev2 and open[1] >= lowerDev3 and open[1] <= lowerDev2 and (obvRsi < 30 or (obvRsi >= 30 and obvRsi[1] < 30)) and ta.adx < 30 

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

plotshape(longCondition, title="Long Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, shape=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)
plotshape(shortCondition, title="Short Signal", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, shape=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)
```

i tried to run this program and the problem is that there seems to be a syntax error at line 27 in the vwap indicator function. im not so good at programming so im not sure why it isn't working. is it due to the fact that there is a function inside a function or is it just a stupid little syntax error ?

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple errors in the above scrip. I have removed all of them by fixing the below issues.

1. Some functions were used from version 4 and some were used from version 5 pinescript. Changed all of them to [version](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/) 5.
2. Functions declared one inside other.
3. Return types were not matching. VWAPIndicator doesn't return tuple.
4. adx is not a function in either versions.
5. shortCondition was not declared.
6. Added cw in local scope of functions.

```js
//@version=5
strategy("HOSS Scalping", overlay=true)
//weighted mean
pine_vwmean(x, y) =>
    cw = 0.0
    cd = 0.0
    w_sum = 0.0
    d_sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
        cd := x[i]
        cw := volume[i]
        d_sum += cw * cd
        w_sum += cw
    d_sum / w_sum

//weighted standard deviation
pine_vwstdev(x, y, b) =>
    d_sum = 0.0
    w_sum = 0.0
    cd = 0.0
    cw = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
        cd := x[i]
        cw := volume[i]
        d_sum += cw * math.pow(cd - b, 2)
        w_sum += cw
    math.sqrt(d_sum / w_sum)

//weighted average deviation
pine_vwavdev(x, y, b) =>
    d_sum = 0.0
    w_sum = 0.0
    cd = 0.0
    cw = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
        cd = x[i]
        cw = volume[i]
        d_sum += cw * math.abs(cd - b)
        w_sum += cw
    d_sum / w_sum

// Custom OBV RSI Indicator
OBVIndicator() =>
    obvsrc = close
    change_1 = ta.change(obvsrc)
    obv = ta.cum(ta.change(obvsrc) > 0 ? volume : change_1 < 0 ? -volume : 0 * volume)

    src = obv
    len = 5
    up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
    down = ta.rma(-1*math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
    rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)
    rsi
// Custom VWAP Indicator
VWAPIndicator() =>
    ls = false
    type = 'Average Deviation'
    length = 60
    source = close
    _low = ls == true ? math.log(low) : low
    _high = ls == true ? math.log(high) : high
    src = ls == true ? math.log(source) : source

    vwmean = pine_vwmean(src, length)

    dev = if type == 'Standard Deviation'
        dev = pine_vwstdev(src, length, vwmean)
        dev
    else if type == 'Average Deviation'
        dev = pine_vwavdev(src, length, vwmean)
        dev

// Long Entry Conditions



obvRsi = OBVIndicator()
adx = 31
dev = VWAPIndicator()
vwmean = dev
lowerDev2 = vwmean - 2 * dev
lowerDev3 = vwmean - 3 * dev

longCondition = close[1] > lowerDev2 and open[1] >= lowerDev3 and open[1] <= lowerDev2 and (obvRsi < 30 or (obvRsi >= 30 and obvRsi[1] < 30)) and adx < 30 
shortCondition = false
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

plotshape(longCondition, title="Long Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)
plotshape(shortCondition, title="Short Signal", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it due to the fact that there is a function inside a function

Yes. You cannot define a function inside another function. Move all the function declarations to global scope. See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html) for more information.